# In wp_query, how can I order by a complex calculated or conditional fields?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

In wp_query, is it possible to build a complex query so I can order by a conditional or calculated fields?
what I'm trying to do is something like the next query in MySql:

```
SELECT *, field1, field2
  case when field1+field2 > some_value then 1 else 2 end as my_alias
FROM my_table
ORDER BY my_alias ASC
```

I want to build queries like this one using wp_query, is this possible? if yes, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: why not just use custom sql query - https://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query ?

Comment: @aeryaguzov because I'm overriding some WordPress plugin code, and I just want to add the order by statement to the long wp_query that  I already have.

Comment: Are you dealing with a custom table? `WP_Query` can be used only to query posts and custom posts. For all custom table (one that has been added by a plugin for example) you need to use [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) instead.

Comment: Thanks @vard, I have a plugin that uses wp_query to query a custom posts and I need to add extra variable in the order by statement, the problem is that the value of the variable is based on a status of the post, to be more clear I have _date_from_ and _date_to_ fields and if current date is before _date_from_ the status is **future**, if the date is after the _date_to_ status is **finished**, else the status is **ongoing**.
I want to display the posts in this order: ongoing, future and then finished so I need to build a query that creates the status as a numeric value and order by this value.

Comment: I see. _date_from_ and _date_to_ are post meta fields (in _wp_postmeta_), right?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you need to

- add custom field using 
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_fields/
- add custom order by using 
  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to do this with a single `WP_Query` as `meta_query` doesn't allow you such flexibility, though you can do three distinct queries then merge them (untested code):

```
// Get ongoing events
$ongoing = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'date_from',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'date_from',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '<=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'date_to',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
));
foreach($ongoing as $key => $ongoing_post) {
    $ongoing_post->event_status = 'ongoing';
    $ongoing[$key] = $ongoing_post;
}

// Get upcoming events
$upcoming = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'date_from',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_from',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '>',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
));
foreach($upcoming as $key => $upcoming_post) {
    $upcoming_post->event_status = 'upcoming';
    $upcoming[$key] = $upcoming_post;
}

// Get past events
$past = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'meta_key' => 'date_from',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_to',
            'value' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'compare' => '<',
            'type' => 'DATE'
        )
    )
));
foreach($past as $key => $past_post) {
    $past_post->past_status = 'past';
    $past[$key] = $past_post;
}

// Merge'em all
$events = array_merge($ongoing, $upcoming, $past);
```

The thing is to use [`meta_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to compare the meta values with the actual date (you may want to change the date format depending of how they are stored in `date_from` and `date_to` fields), and do a little loop right after to add a property to all post object with the right `event_status` which you can work with when displaying posts.

Maybe there is a clever way to achieve this through [WP_Query filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters) but it would need more in-depth investigation inside `WP_Query` source code as it is not really documented inside the codex.

Comment: Thanks @vard for your time, I needed it to be in a single query because I have pagination and the parameters for it are in the query itself. anyway I ended up adding a new custom field for the status, and I'm updating it when needed so I can order by this field, and it's working :)

Answer (score 0):

I thing You use, and try this,

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT *, field1, field2 case when field1+field2 > some_value then 1 else 2 end as my_alias FROM my_table ORDER BY my_alias ASC");
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Look at this [Click Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)